# 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classifier'

Tags: opencv, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, torchvision

How to find in_features of a Pytorch model? model.classifier.in_features is working on densenet121 but nit on vgg18, is there any function which may work on all torchvision models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classifier` is a `Sequential` module in the `VGG`'s implementation, so, if you want to access the `in_features` passed to the `classifier`, you have to check the `in_features` of the first layer.

```py
models.vgg19().classifier[0].in_features
```

It seems like different implementations follow different patterns, so the best way to determine `in_features` for all the models would be to check the source code directly.